# how to pass data from one view to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I want to pass object data from one view to another on click of button.
I am calling the action to load the second view via ajax.
In the controller action I am trying to pass object data to view. But the view is not rendered.
How can I achieve the scenario of passing data from one view and populating it to the controls of other view?

Comment: Please add the code you tried for better understanding. It is difficult with out seeing a code

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to pass object data from one view to another on click of button

When in any `Action` or `ActionResult` you have

`return RedirectToAction("controllerName","viewname","parameters")`

so the Action Method instead of returning a view, this will redirect to another view Action method and that view will be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the data from one view to another in form of query string or post parameters to an action.

Ex:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PassData(string dataFromView1)
{

 return View("View2", dataFromView1);
}
```

**Note:** Here i used a single string data in a parameter. If your View1 has more data/complex data structure, better to use ViewModel class and pass that to your intermediate controller.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to pass object data from one view to another on click of button

You need to pass **View** in `HttpPost` method. Look at this code.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourActionName(Model model)
{
  return View("AnotherActionName", model);
}
```

Or you can use `RedirectToAction`.

Comment: I am having area so the above code wont work. I have to pass a model from one view in one area to another view in another area. So first how will I pass the value from first view to the controller, once first view to controller is done then only from controller i can redirect it to second view.